# Google Maps Tutorial mContext cannot be resolved

Tags: android, maps, android-context

I have successfully completed 5 of the android developers tutorials but I am having a problem with the Google Maps tutorial.  I have entered the code letter for letter and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to import all the packages and I am still getting an error that `mContext` cannot be resolved.  I'm sure its something simple, I've just been staring at the screen too long to see it.

```
package com.example.HelloGoogleMaps;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

import com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

public class HelloItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
}

public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
mOverlays.add(overlay);
populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

public HelloItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
super(defaultMarker);
mContext = context; //ERROR #1
} 

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); //ERROR #2
dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
dialog.show();
return true;
}



}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignment somewhere.

```
Context mContext;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I added the assignment above the first instance and Eclipse just throws a warning (local variable mContext is never read):

     Context mContext;
     mContext = context;

I also added the assignment above the second instance and I get a new error (the local variable mContext may not have been initialized):
   Context mContext;
   AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.  Thanks Outcast.  I placed the assignment at the top as the first line of the HelloItemizedOverlay Class.  Once I did that all errors when away and the app ran smoothly.

Comment: You're welcome.I'm poor at English.I should say something like"Declaration and Initialazition before you use it."That'll be clearer.Well,as you should be careful about your code,I should be careful about my speaking.By the way,Happy New Year!!!